# Swagger is showing _ebean_intercept with everymodel in my play application

Tags: java, playframework

I am integrating swagger into my play application. It works fine. ( Play 2.2 + swagger 1.3.3 )

Although for every model it adds a field which I need to hide

```
Classification {
    id (integer, optional),
    type (string, optional),
    shortCode (string, optional),
    active (boolean, optional),
    **_ebean_intercept (EntityBeanIntercept, optional)**
}
```

I created a custom converter in Scala ( My app is written in Java by the way )

```
class IgnoreConverter extends SwaggerSchemaConverter {
    override def skippedClasses: Set[String] =    Set("com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept")
    override def ignoredClasses: Set[String] =  Set("com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept")
    override def ignoredPackages: Set[String] = Set("com.avaje.ebean")
}
```

I am adding this converter when the Play app is loaded via Globals.java

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application application) {
    Logger.info("Registering custom converter");
    //HideModelConverter converter = new HideModelConverter();
    IgnoreConverter converter = new IgnoreConverter();

    ModelConverters.addConverter(converter, true);
}
```

Still no luck.

Can someone give me some ideas where I should look ?

How can I hide fields, classes, packages from Swagger's from introspection ?
Why is Swagger ignoring my converter ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Definitely something weird going on here. If you look at [Swagger's own example](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models#excluding-fields-with-a-custom-model-converter-131-and-greater) it should work. I tried this and what's strange is that when I first start my app it contains the `EntityBeanIntercept` property, however (with your config), if I then change something and the app reloads, the `EntityBeanIntercept` property is no longer included. Almost as if the first time round the converter is not read in time but is in place for future requests. Can you confirm?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to answer! Well, For me it is very consistent. It is always there. I am not sure if it has something to do with classloader issue ? E.g. Swagger is running in a different classloader or if it is due to byecode enhancement of ebean but I struggle to figure out how I can debug this. Any idea of how you can debug this bit ? Thanks!

Comment: No problem, it's a strange one alright. I think you should [log an issue](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-play2) with Swagger. The example they provide doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having this same problem. I think it comes from the Swagger module being loaded before onStart() has a chance to run. And thus if you change something, the application reloads and it works fine.

I fixed it on my end by changing the loading from onStart to beforeStart:

```
@Override
public void beforeStart(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Registering custom converter");
    ModelConverters.addConverter(new IgnoreConverter(), true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been looking for this for months. :) Finally I do not need see those _ebean_intercept items in my code.

Comment: You are missing the IgnoreConverter class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class as explained in the following link [swagger ebean](http://www.tagwith.com/question_1242768_swagger-is-showing-ebean-intercept-with-everymodel-in-my-play-application)

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.converter.SwaggerSchemaConverter

class IgnoreConverter extends SwaggerSchemaConverter{
  override def skippedClasses: Set[String] = Set("com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept")
  override def ignoredClasses: Set[String] = Set("com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept")
  override def ignoredPackages: Set[String] = Set("com.avaje.ebean")
}
```

You can now follow the step explained by Luis,

```
public class Global  extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application app) {
        Logger.info("Registering custom converter");
        ModelConverters.addConverter(new IgnoreConverter(), true);
    }
}
```